# [__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil

Tags: xcode, null, sigabrt

For some reason that I cannot find I am getting the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
```

As I am quite new in xCode i'd like some help. 
The application crashes in the following line:

```
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

in the ASAppDelegate.m file.

The whole function is like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
// Override point for customization after application launch.

AS_MainViewController *MyrootViewController = [[AS_MainViewController alloc]
                        initWithNibName:@"AS_MainViewController" bundle: [NSBundle mainBundle]];

self.window.rootViewController = MyrootViewController;

self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

return YES;
}
```

Could you please help me?

Thank you.

Comment: i think problem is not here,may be in your viewController class.

Comment: Either the object you are trying to insert is nil or you are trying to insert objects by skipping beforehand indexes. In both cases you can't. This is a very helpful read: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Collections.html

Comment: you mean my xib file?

Comment: but I do not see somewhere to try to insert something?

Comment: it would help if you had a stack trace, or line where this is happening. You should add a breakpoint on all Objective-C exceptions.

Comment: I have placed brake points and the application crashes at this line as I have written before:[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally the error has been resolved. I started a new empty project and did all the work from the beginning. As I was also copy-pasting from the old one, step by step I was also running each time in every step. The application run without problems. 
I finished it and now it runs. I could ever understand why and what this error was, but in a new project (having the same code with the old one) the problem does not exist!

Anyway, thank you for your help.

Comment: and the real problem was that an object has been forgotten and not synthesized.