# object cannot be nil - On a segue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

All I want to do in my code is move from one view to another. No matter how many different ways I try to go around it, any segue or any change from the current view causes this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
```

There's no indication of what object it's talking about at all, and the app is crashing on my segue line. Oh and I'm using Xcode 5-DP and iOS 7. Here's my source:

LoginViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ECSlidingViewController.h"
#import "MenuViewController.h"
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *userTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *passwordTextField;

- (IBAction)signupTouched:(UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)logInPressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)backgroundTouched:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)revealMenu:(id)sender;
@end
```

LoginViewController.m (Exception on line 8)

```
#import "LoginViewController.h"
#import "RegisterView.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@implementation LoginViewController

- (IBAction)signupTouched:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"signup" sender:self];
    //                    THE APPLICATION CRASHES ON THIS LINE ABOVE
}

//Login button pressed
-(IBAction)logInPressed:(id)sender
{
    //If user logged succesful:
    //[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginSuccesful" sender:self];

    if (![self.userTextField.text isEqual:@""]) {
        [PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:self.userTextField.text password:self.passwordTextField.text block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
            if (user) {
                //Open the wall
                //[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginSuccesful" sender:self];
                UIAlertView *loginAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Great!"  message:@"You have logged in" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Get roaming" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [loginAlertView show];
            } else {
                //Something bad has ocurred
                NSString *errorString = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"];
                UIAlertView *errorAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:errorString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [errorAlertView show];
            }
        }];
    } else {
        //Something bad has ocurred
        NSString *errorString = @"You did not type any credentials!";
        UIAlertView *errorAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:errorString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [errorAlertView show];
    }
}

- (IBAction)backgroundTouched:(id)sender {
    [self.userTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.passwordTextField resignFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (![self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController isKindOfClass:[MenuViewController class]]) {
        self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Menu"];
    }
    self.slidingViewController.underRightViewController = nil;

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.slidingViewController.panGesture];
}

- (IBAction)revealMenu:(id)sender
{
    [self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewTo:ECRight];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.userTextField.delegate = self;
    self.passwordTextField.delegate = self;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [self setUserTextField:nil];
    [self setPasswordTextField:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
@end
```

I've googled, and I've googled. No-one else seems to be having an issue like this. I tried cleaning out my entire iOS Simulator and everything to no avail, following a solution that appeared to work for others. I've tried every type of segue possible and none are working.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you declared segue name in storyboard?

Comment: what is happening in the controller on the destination end of the segue with identifier "signup"?  what is happing in `prepareForSegue:sender:`?

Comment: There is no prepareforsegue, I'm not really passing any data I just want a the view to load. And yes I have a manual segue called signup setup in storyboard, which links to the view I want to load. Nothing is happening in the signup view when it loads, it crashes no matter what view I try to load, even if it's one that's already been displayed and loads fine.

Comment: Search all lines in your project where you call *insertObject:atIndex:*, add a *NSLog* call where you print the object argument that you're inserting, you'll probably notice that some pointer bill be *nil*, because of some memory management error.

Comment: Sometimes, It might be easier to create a project from scratch http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15812899/nsarraym-insertobjectatindex-object-cannot-be-nil

Comment: Oh noes hahah it's a pretty big project :L

Comment: You shouldn't need that IBAction if you are using storyboards. You should be able to just link your segue to the destination view controller from the Storyboard by right clicking the button and dragging to the new view controller.

Comment: That's true, I actually did it this way because I couldn't work out why it was crashing, even if I do the link directly from button to view in storyboard I still get the crash :(

Comment: I think the problem may be something to do with your use of the ECSlidingViewController, did you set up and configure the topviewcontroller correctly?

Comment: Is your destination segue perhaps embedded in a UINavigationController?

Comment: Here is another existing solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966149/core-data-crash-nsarraym-insertobjectatindex-object-cannot-be-nil

Comment: Orange, make that an answer because it lead me to work out why it wasn't working.

When working with ECSlidingViewController you can't actually use segues, it causes a crash. Therefore you have to create a method in the underLeftView (ECSlidingViewController is one of those swipe-for-menu implementations, like the facebook app or the youtube app) that will set the topview for you.

Pretty long winded but it works - and it was a very long undocumented adventure to it.

Comment: @Gergy008 Cool, just did!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recheck your configuration and use of the ECSlidingViewController, and it's topViewController.

Comment: Thx - that helped!
My `destinationViewController` was subclassing a custom class of mine, which was setting itself as topViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Check in signup.xib if the UIView is connected to an outlet.

Comment: I don't use .xibs I use storyboards